# What is kintegrityd and why it has -20 nice value?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, top, nice

I have a Linux distro in my laptop, with 3.18.17, 32-bit Kernel.
Running `top` has listed below output,

[image]

I am aware a little about nice and renice of process in Linux. 
Looking into top, I understood there are 6 processes, which have nice value of -20. I am totally convinced why kworker, khelper and crypto have -20 nice value.

Can anyone tell me what is "kintegrityd" and why it has -20 nice value?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-purpose-of-kintegrityd-Linux-Kernel-Daemon/answer/Liran-Ben-Haim) it checks the integrity of block devices by writing data to them and checking that it has not changed.

[This](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/block/bio-integrity.c) seems to be the file in which it is defined. Line 469 seems to be giving it high priority.

Answer (score 0):

The `kintegrityd` [work queue](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/understanding-the-linux/0596005652/ch04s08.html) implements data integrity extensions for block I/O. All kernel work queues are -20 nice by default. This system is also known as `bio-integrity`, which is a much more effective search term. The author is Martin K. Petersen, from Oracle. The kernel documentation is [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/data-integrity.txt) and the source code is [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/44d7d3b0d1cdb2119dba33bbedd602ce30528d6c/block/bio-integrity.c).